# implementation of is_aggregate_initializable does not work with MinGW64

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae, mingw-w64

I need to use a traits function that deduces if a type can be aggregate initialized from given arguments. Typically it is like `std::is_constructible`, but uses aggregate initialization in `decltype()`.

```
template<typename POD, typename Tuple, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_aggregate_initializable_from_tuple : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename POD, typename ... Types>
struct is_aggregate_initializable_from_tuple<POD, std::tuple<Types...>, void_t<decltype(POD{Types()...})>>
        : std::true_type
{
};

template<typename T, typename ... From>
struct is_aggregate_initializable : is_aggregate_initializable_from_tuple<T, std::tuple<From...>>
{
};
```

This works with MSVC and C++11, but does not compile with MinGW64.
However it does compile with MinGW64 with C++14.

```
#include <string>

struct abc
{
    int a = 4;
    float b = 8.15f;
    char c = 'c',
            d = 'd';
    int e = 16;
    double f = 23.42;
    std::string g = "oceanic";
};

int main()
{

    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float, char>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float, char, char>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float, char, char, int>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float, char, char, int, double>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, int, float, char, char, int, double, std::string>(), "Unexpected");
    static_assert(detail::is_aggregate_initializable<abc, abc>(), "Unexpected");

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a bug? What am I doing wrong?

---

I've noticed that even `abc a{int()};` does not compile with MinGW64 C++11. I don't understand...

Comment: What compiler error do you get?  Also, the syntax `T{args...}` isn't just for aggregates.  Uniform initialization allows `{}` to call constructors as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't get any apart from assertion failures.

Comment: Which assert fails?

Comment: @NathanOliver all of them except `<abc>` and `<abc, abc>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out.

From C++11 to C++14 an aggregate requires to have [no default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).
That is why I can't initialize `abc`. If it had no defaulted members, it would compile.